# Interpreting SQL's BNF

Tags: sql, syntax, bnf

I'm looking at the syntax of SQL, specifically the [character string literal](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#character%20string%20literal).

```
<character string literal> ::=
    [ <introducer> <character set specification> ]
    <quote> [ <character representation> ... ] <quote>
    [ { <separator> <quote> [ <character representation> ... ] <quote> }... ]
```

Ignoring the `[ <introducer> <character set specification> ]` part, does this mean one or more `<quote> [ <character representation> ... ] <quote>`s separated by a `<separator>`?

If so, does that mean that `'hello' 'world'` should be parsed as one `<character string literal>`?

For the query `SELECT 'hello' 'world'`, Microsoft SQL Server 2005 returns:

```
+-------+
| world |
+-------+
| hello |
+-------+
```

and MySQL 5.0 returns:

```
+------------+
| hello      |
+------------+
| helloworld |
+------------+
```

I understand that every flavor of SQL is different, and that they don't all follow the standard. I'm just trying to determine whether I'm interpreting the BNF correctly. Thanks.

Comment: A minor layout point: SQL server returns the value "hello" with the column header world. "world" is interpreted as an alias/identifier. And good question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If so, does that mean that 'hello' 'world' should be parsed as one ?

According to ANSI SQL, yes.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what is happening in SQL Server, what you're actually doing is returning 'hello' with a column name of 'world'. Your example is the same as:

```
SELECT 'hello' AS 'world'
```

If you tried to extend your thought further, you'd get an error:

```
SELECT 'hello' 'world' 'now'

Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'now'.
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually understood that from the beginning. My main question is regarding the BNF.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the BNF for `<separator> ::=`.

Comment: and then what? I can't see how this helps.

Comment: I interpret it as one or more <comment>s or <whitespace>s.